# Cast string to number

Tags: hooks

Actually, I am using `pre_get_posts` hook with these configure

```
 $metaquery = array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key' => 'price',
                    'value' => array(80,100),
                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
                )
  );
$query->set( 'meta_query', $metaquery );
```

However all the price values are saved under data type of string, so `$query` does not return the expected result because `BETWEEN` are treated as comparing 2 strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WP doesn't "look" at the type of data you have, it just has a default of CHAR.  So if you dump your current query you will see respective type cast: `CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR)`.

To make it work you need to specify type argument explicitly `'type' => 'NUMERIC'` and CAST will change accordingly: `CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED)`.

See [Custom Field Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) in Codex for more on supported types.

For the record here is how you can dump generated SQL, without involving too many moving parts:

```
$meta_query_args = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key'     => 'price',
        'value'   => array( 80, 100 ),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
    ),
);

$meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query( $meta_query_args );
$sql        = $meta_query->get_sql( 'post', $wpdb->posts, 'ID' );

/*
array (2) [
    'join' => string (64) " INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )"
    'where' => string (112) " AND (
  ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'price' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) BETWEEN '80' AND '100' )
)"
]
*/
```

Comment: You saved my life, I just need 'type'    => 'NUMERIC' in this case. Thanks so much!